# Capture UserControl's Linkbutton event in inside an updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a UserControl call itemUserControl inside an Update Panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <STX:ItemControl ID="itemUserControl" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Inside the UserControl I have a link button with an OnClick event which I hope to capture from within the user control's code behind.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" Text="ClickMe" OnClick="lnkBtn_Click" />
```

I can't seem to get it working :(
From Googling around it looks like I need to add the Triggers to wire up the button click event.

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBtn" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

However, I can't add this Trigger on the parent page right after the ContentTemplate tag because Visual Studio doesn't see the button ID.  Is there a way to do this? I just want the button event to fire on the user control's code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<Triggers>` from your containing page and add following lines in Page_Load event of containing page

ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(MyControl.FindControl("lnkBtn"));

This will register your usercontrol and click event of link button will be fired on click

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to capture anything unless you want the button to perform a full PostBack. If you just add the `lnkBtn_Click` method in the code behind of the User Control it will be handled Async.

If you do want a full PostBack, register the button to that event in the `Page_load` of the UserControl.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lnkBtn);
}
```